# What is implementation of Client API to interact with Hydra+JsonLd Web API?

Tags: jena, semantic-web, json-ld, apache-jena, hydra-core

I think they ([API Platform](https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/)) are developing server side implementation using JsonLd + Hydra .If they are doing at server side .How are they implementing Client side API to interact with this Web(Server Side) API?